# Up and down arrows in adb shell

Tags: adb

I have an HTC Desire HD. When I connect to it with adb shell from Windows, the up and down arrow keys work fine and I get command history. But when I connect to it from Mac OS, the up and down arrows show up as ^[[A and ^[[B.

Is there a way to fix the mac OS terminal to work like the DOS one?

Thank you very much!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478231/working-with-the-android-shell-under-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What shell is running on the phone? - You can find out with `ps`

I seem to remember having this issue a while ago (but haven't run in to it recently on my current phone) when logging in to plain `sh`, executing `bash` or `ash` immediately after connecting was a simple workaround

Comment: Thank you! This worked. There is no bash but there is ash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MAC user per say, but here's a solution reported working:

Type in terminal:

```
adb shell telnetd &
adb forward tcp:9999 tcp:23
telnet localhost 9999
```

---

Credits to the user [alapapa @ xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=4111241&postcount=5).

See the entire [thread here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=535014).